# Taking and filtering MYSQL results on another params table

Tags: mysql, database

### [image]

Please help me with the query.
I want to get all projects_ids, that contain params and values of params.
When i use one criteria (not three, as an image) - it works and gaing results!

When use all, I think the CPU is trying to get a record when sometimes 3 criterion are passed. Need to get all `projects_ids` that contains criterion.

Comment: can you provide the DB structure and output you want?

Comment: projects - table (id, title); projectparams - table (id, title); projects_projectparams - table (id, projects_id, projectparams_id, value);

Answer (score 0):

My solution at this time is SELF-JOIN.
For each param i create "JOIN" to table ON "projects_id", and add more WHERE statements with new tables.

10 params = 10 joins.